# script tag content doesnt get found via requests html (python)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, python-requests

i have a page where i want to extract a ean number from a script tag (here it is 8806090571589)

I tried to get the script firstly with

```
        jsonn = r.html.find('script')[3].text
        print(title, price, jsonn)
```

however that didnt work.

the source code of the page is on here (too long to post):

view-source:https://www.kaufland.de/product/361834606/?search_value=waschmaschine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use find(), it will return only the first occurrence of the tag. Since I can see that you need to find the 4th occurrence, you need to use the findAll() function. It will return a list of all the occurrences and then you can use any occurrence according to your needs.

I've tried using the below given code on my computer -

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.kaufland.de/product/361834606/?search_value=waschmaschine"

response = urllib3.PoolManager().request("GET", URL, headers={'User-Agent' : "python"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')

print(soup.findAll("script")[3])
```

You can take this code for reference and modify as per your needs.